# Is there a VNC (remote desktop) software that can successfully launch Blender..?

Tags: modeling

Is there a VNC (remote desktop) software that can successfully launch Blender?

I tested a few (Linux server and Linux client). For example X2Go works for all other software except Blender.

Only Blender 2.79 in software-gl mode launches. Blender 2.79 and Blender 2.83 (both in normal and software-ql mode) crash.

I guess it is the VNC software's fault. Here is X2Go's crash report:

```
> # backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x6989e9d]
./blender() [0xc1548f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f601308ef20]
./blender(_Z33GHOST_X11_ApplicationErrorHandlerP9_XDisplayP11XErrorEvent+0x11) [0x17304f1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x11a) [0x7f60142d18fa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3d82b) [0x7f60142ce82b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3d8d5) [0x7f60142ce8d5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XReply+0x240) [0x7f60142cf830]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6(XListInputDevices+0x84) [0x7f6014086d44]
./blender(_ZN15GHOST_SystemX1120refreshXInputDevicesEv+0x5f) [0x1731a3f]
./blender(_ZN15GHOST_SystemX11C1Ev+0x453) [0x1732193]
./blender(_ZN13GHOST_ISystem12createSystemEv+0x35) [0x172eda5]
./blender(GHOST_CreateSystem+0x9) [0x172dc29]
./blender(wm_ghost_init+0x2d) [0xee800d]
./blender(WM_init+0x275) [0xed4135]
./blender(main+0x2a3) [0xb4bf53]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f6013071b97]
./blender() [0xc11c0c]
```

There are many Open Source remote desktop applications out there. Somebody may know which OSS application works or which one works after some tweaking..?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found this in Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/blender

I've tried it on my EC2 server(CPU only) and it ran perfectly.
This docker is using KasmVNC.

https://github.com/kasmtech/KasmVNC

By the way, there's an official web-VNC Blender demo from KasmVNC:
https://app.kasmweb.com/#/cast/8183460092

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182259)

Answer (score 0):

I've used blender successfully with [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/linux/).

Comment: Thanks but the solution should be open source :(

Comment: Did you mean it didn't crash when using the RealVNC client or RealVNC server, or both? What did you use as client or server?

Comment: It means i used both, server and client to control a few computers running blender remotely. I have no clue, nor do I care if they are opensource, it worked for me. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

I heard about people using [ThinLinc](https://www.cendio.com) for this purpose (found one video in Portuguese) https://youtu.be/dU0sAeDbcHY?list=PLXOK6XjgmOFyiODs_r5uFIAaHQ40RFG0O&t=1749